PHP script showing as a page
So recently I started coding websites for fun and now I'm trying to write a php script which will collect the data from it after clicking "submit", but when I click it, it shows a black page with the php script.
I tried reinstalling XAMPP but it did nothing.
My folder with HTML's, CSS and all that stuff is in the htdocs folder.
Apache and mySQL are up and running fine.
PHP is installed and works if I check the version in CMD.
I have no idea what to do.
PSA. Sorry if that's a stupid and easy to solve problem but I'm a complete noob so yk.
